# Rely on multiple tables inside a nested select and a delete MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to write a dual MySQL query which archives the content of a table to another table, then deletes the original row in the original table.

I have the base query working just fine in other areas. The query below relies on a second table to help select which rows need to be archived & deleted.

I am getting a syntax error where the AS appears in the nested select of the first query and near the AS in the delete query.

I have researched and researched and tried a bunch of different code combos, but I can't get the queries working. The queries are written in PHP using PDO, so please ignore the PDO tags, they are not the problem.

```
INSERT INTO usetwca (r_id, c_id, o_id, t_id, s_id, ip_address, timestamp, timestamp_archived) SELECT :r_id, usetwc.c_id, usetwc.o_id, usetwc.t_id, usetwc.s_id, usetwc.ip_address, usetwc.timestamp, :timestamp FROM usetwc JOIN useo ON useo.o_id = usetwc.o_id AND useo.best_fit IS NULL WHERE usetwc.user_id = :user_id;

DELETE FROM usetwc JOIN useo ON useo.o_id = usetwc.o_id AND useo.best_fit IS NULL WHERE usetwc.user_id = :user_id;
```

Comment: Any reason why you didn't implement this as a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on the `users_sessions_exercise_t_ws_correlation' table?

Comment: @Declan_K can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my queries working.

```
INSERT INTO usetwca (r_id, c_id, o_id, t_id, s_id, ip_address, timestamp, timestamp_archived) SELECT :r_id, usetwc.c_id, usetwc.o_id, usetwc.t_id, usetwc.s_id, usetwc.ip_address, usetwc.timestamp, :timestamp FROM usetwc JOIN useo ON useo.o_id = usetwc.o_id AND useo.best_fit IS NULL WHERE usetwc.user_id = :user_id;

DELETE usetwc FROM usetwc INNER JOIN useo ON useo.o_id = usetwc.o_id AND useo.best_fit IS NULL WHERE usetwc.user_id = :user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement this as a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on the `users_sessions_exercise_t_ws_correlation' table.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374383/saving-the-user-id-of-a-user-that-deleted-a-record-with-a-trigger-in-mysql) as a good example.

Here's a good general reference on using [Triggers for Logging](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/176-how-to-use-a-trigger-to-log-changes-to-a-table-in-mysql/).

Comment: Humm, very interesting I have about 50 archive/delete queries in this new project. I will explore the MySQL triggers concept a little further.

Do you know how I might be able to fix the above queries if I decide not to use triggers?